# How to check a specific alphabet in tuple first and move to the next alphabet in python?

Tags: python, loops, if-statement, tuples

i am trying to solve the morse code translator program. When i tried to encode the message the order of the morse code is not correct. I think it's because of the if statement as it displays the value what it finds first. Are there any alternatives for the if statement. I am specifically using the same function and need to access value from following tuple:

```
`MORSE_CODE = (
           ("-...", "B"), (".-", "A"), ("-.-.", "C"), 
           ("-..", "D"), (".", "E"),("..-.", "F"),
           ("--.", "G"),("....", "H"), ("..", "I"), 
           (".---", "J"),("-.-", "K"), (".-..", "L"), 
           ("--", "M"), ("-.", "N"),("---", "O"), 
           (".--.", "P"), ("--.-", "Q"), (".-.", "R"), 
           ("...", "S"),("-", "T"), ("..-", "U"),
           ("...-", "V"),(".--", "W"), ("-..-", "X"),
           ("-.--", "Y"), ("--..", "Z"), (".-.-.-", "."), 
           ("-----", "0"),(".----", "1"), ("..---", "2"), 
           ("...--", "3"), ("....-", "4"), (".....", "5"),
           ("-....", "6"), ("--...", "7"), ("---..", "8"),
           ("----.", "9"),("-.--.", "("), ("-.--.-", ")"), 
           (".-...", "&"), ("---...", ":"), ("-.-.-.", ";"), 
           ("-...-", "="), (".-.-.", "+"), ("-....-", "-"), 
           ("..--.-", "_"), (".-..-.", '"'), ("...-..-", "$"), 
           (".--.-.", "@"), ("..--..", "?"), ("-.-.--", "!")
           )`

def encode(message):
    while True:
        words = [message]
        words[:] = message
        for i in range(0, len(MORSE_CODE)):
            for j in range(0, len(words)):
                if words[j] in MORSE_CODE[i][1]:
                    encoded_message = str(MORSE_CODE[i][0])
                    print(encoded_message, end=" ")
        mode = str.upper(input("Would you like to encode/decode another message?y/n"))
        if mode == 'Y':
            encode(get_input())
            break
        elif mode == 'N':
            print('Thanks for using the program :) GoodBye!!!')
            break
    return encoded_message
```

The output order is not correct:
[image: Here is the output]

Comment: Use dictionaries instead of tuples for things like this.

Comment: I need to specifically use tuple for this task.

Comment: Change the order of the loops. Currently you go over the alphabet and print letters in the message. So you will just print all the letters in alphabetical order. You need to run over the letters of the message and print their Morse value.

Comment: Can you explain why you have to use tuples? As has already been said, dictionaries are the way to go here. Also you need to consider what happens if a character in the message cannot be found. Do you just ignore it?

Comment: Its a task that i need to finish using the tuple and i cant use dictionary or other lists.@igrinis i tried doing that it changed nothing could you please show me how its done